# Google Maps - Given a Adress, State & ZIP, how can I dynamically create a ext link to GMAPs?

Tags: google-maps

I have a user profile page on my web app which has contact information. I'm like a GMAPs icon that when clicked opens a new with Google Maps, and has the contact information pre-populated and submitted. Is there a simple way to do this without having to call APIs to generate a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this as the `href` attribute:

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=[INSERT_ADDRESS_HERE]

In the address, you could convert ALL SPACES to "+".

Example: http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=1056+33rd+st+Grand+Rapids+MI+49508